# Battery drain notification on although there is no battery drain on Huawei P10 Lite Android 8

Tags: android

A colleague of mine gets the notification that an app I helped develope drains her battery quickly when it's in the background. So far she is the first person I know of to get this notification with our app.

Let me describe what the app does/needs: When the user starts the app the device is localised once. After that the user has to push a button to update their position. Whenever the user switches to a specific activity the server is pinged to update the data in the app. There no other permissions than GPS required to use the app. The server is only pinged and the location is only updated when the app is used actively.

This is the code for the server communication.

```
/**
 * Queries for Stores in the BoundingBox defined by the given GeoCoordinates.
 * After the Async- Query was successful the Stores which are in the Resultset but currently not
 * loaded are queryed for and added to the global Adapter and an
 * ID-Filter is put in place limiting the List to the retrieved ones.
 *
 * @param topLeft     TopLeft- Coordinates for the Query
 * @param bottomRight BottomRight- Coordinates for the Query
 */
private void queryForStoresInBoundingBox(lokalfuchs.de.lokalfuchs.api.model.Location topLeft, lokalfuchs.de.lokalfuchs.api.model.Location bottomRight) {

    //query elasticsearch for all stores in the given region
    StoreService.getInstance().queryForStoresInGeoPointBoundingBox(
            topLeft, bottomRight, new ElasticsearchQueryCallback() {
                @Override
                public void querySuccesful(final List<Integer> ids) {
                    //from the list of ids which lie in the currently visible region: determine which are not currently loaded
                    final List<Integer> missingStores = StoreService.getInstance().getStoreAdapter().findMissingItemIds(ids);
                    final List<Integer> missingOffers = OfferService.getInstance().findMissingStoreIds(ids);
                    if (!missingStores.isEmpty()) {
                        //request these missing items and add them in the adapter
                        StoreService.getInstance().requestStores(null, null, missingStores.toArray(new Integer[missingStores.size()]), new StoreRequestCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void requestSuccesful(final List<Store> stores) {
                                // !! TODO dont ask for offers without out valid offer ids you will get from elastic search!
                                OfferService.getInstance().requestOffers(null, missingOffers.toArray(new Integer[missingOffers.size()]), null, null, new OfferRequestCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void requestSuccesful(final List<Offer> offers) {

                                        // TODO replace quick fix, just fetching valid offers with elastic offerIds
                                        // only continue with valid offers
                                        final List<Offer> validOffers = new ArrayList<>();

                                        SimpleDateFormat parserEndDate = new SimpleDateFormat(getResources().getString(R.string.date_pattern));
                                        Date currentDate = new Date();
                                        for (Offer offer : offers) {
                                            try {
                                                Date endDate = parserEndDate.parse(offer.getEndDate());

                                                if (endDate != null && currentDate.compareTo(endDate) < 0) {
                                                    validOffers.add(offer);
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        //add to adapter on ui-thread
                                        MapActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                Map<Integer, List<Integer>> allStoreOffers = OfferService.getInstance().getOffers();
                                                ItemAdapter adapter = OfferService.getInstance().getOfferAdapter();

                                                final List<Offer> handledOffers = (LocationService.getInstance().getLastLocation() != null) ? OfferService.getInstance().calculateDistancesAndRemoveExpiredOffers(
                                                        validOffers, new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(LocationService.getInstance().getLastLocation().getLatitude(), LocationService.getInstance().getLastLocation().getLongitude())) : validOffers;

                                                for (Offer o : handledOffers) {
                                                    OfferService.getInstance().getOfferAdapter().getItems().put(o.getId(), o);
                                                    List<Integer> storeOffers = allStoreOffers.get(o.getStoreId());
                                                    if (storeOffers == null) {
                                                        storeOffers = new ArrayList<>();
                                                        allStoreOffers.put(o.getStoreId(), storeOffers);
                                                    }
                                                    if (!storeOffers.contains(o.getId())) {
                                                        storeOffers.add(o.getId());
                                                        adapter.getItems().put(o.getId(), o);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                Map<Integer, MappableItem> list = StoreService.getInstance().getStoreAdapter().getItems();

                                                for (Store store : stores)
                                                    list.put(store.getId(), store);
                                                StoreService.getInstance().getStoreAdapter().setIdFilter(new ItemIdFilter(ids));
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void requestFailed(int errorCode) {
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void requestFailed(int errorCode) {

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        //there are no missing items - add the filter immediately instead of after the query
                        StoreService.getInstance().getStoreAdapter().setIdFilter(new ItemIdFilter(ids));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void queryFailed() {

                }
            });
}

public void queryForStoresInGeoPointBoundingBox(@NonNull Location top_left, @NonNull Location bottom_right, final @NonNull ElasticsearchQueryCallback callback) {

    //if the coordinates are not correctly ordered reoder them
    if (top_left.getLat() < bottom_right.getLat()) {
        Double temp = top_left.getLat();
        top_left.setLat(bottom_right.getLat());
        bottom_right.setLat(temp);
    }
    if (top_left.getLon() > bottom_right.getLon()) {
        Double temp = top_left.getLon();
        top_left.setLon(bottom_right.getLon());
        bottom_right.setLon(temp);
    }

    this.elasticSearchInterface.elasticSearchStoreIdsGeopointRequest(new ElasticSearchInterface.SearchQuery(top_left, bottom_right, false), LokalFuchs.DEFAULT_SIZE).enqueue(new Callback<ElasticSearchInterface.SearchResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ElasticSearchInterface.SearchResult> call, Response<ElasticSearchInterface.SearchResult> response) {
            //check for response-code 200
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                //prepare resultlist
                List<Integer> storeIds = new ArrayList<>();

                //and iterate over all hits extracting the ids
                for (ElasticSearchInterface.SearchResult.Hits hit : response.body().hits.hits) {
                    if (hit.fields.id.length > 0)
                        storeIds.add(hit.fields.id[0]);
                }
                callback.querySuccesful(storeIds);
            } else {
                callback.queryFailed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ElasticSearchInterface.SearchResult> call, Throwable t) {
            callback.queryFailed();
        }
    });

}
```

I forgot to mention that the data takes a long time to load, probably more than 4 seconds.

This is the code for the localisation.

```
/**
 * asking for localisation permission
 * <p>
 * if ok:
 * start location updates 
 * if not set isRequesting to false
 *
 * @param activity Activity
 */
public boolean requestLocation(Activity activity) {

    if (AppService.getInstance().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, activity, R.string.missing_gps_permission, null)) {
        this.isRequesting = true;
             this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

 /**
 * register Callback for change of position
 *
 * @param locationChangedCallback Callback für for position change
 */
public void registerCallback(LocationChangedCallback locationChangedCallback) {
    if (!this.locationChangedCallbacks.contains(locationChangedCallback)) {
        this.locationChangedCallbacks.add(locationChangedCallback);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
[...]
    //register for location-changes and request the location once
    Location location = LocationService.getInstance().getLastLocation();

    //if we have a location use it
    if (location == null) {
        this.googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        this.googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(52.520008, 13.404954)));
        LocationService.getInstance().registerCallback(this);
        LocationService.getInstance().requestLocation(this);
    } else {
        LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        this.markMyPosition(position);
        this.googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        this.googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
    }
[...]
}
```

I checked the battery drain details on her phone and the CPU doesn't have much to do even when the app is active and the GPS is only used for less then 10 seconds. The app has downloaded 20 mb during past 30 days. Still she gets the notification after like 15 minutes and she has to close it to get rid of the notification. She didn't have this problem with any other app so far nor did anyone else report this issue so far.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be or what I could do to find out what causes this problem?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to know what the answer to the question is without seeing some code related to how you use the GPS, and how you communicate with the server. Are you doing the bulk of the work on the main thread? Are you taking advantage of the JobScheduler to do your work? But based on your description of the app, things sound find. So it's either the more technical details or it's just the common cases of 'Battery Drain Detection' apps throwing false positives for whatever criteria they use.

Comment: How can you be sure that your app is draining the battery>

Comment: @ManojPerumarath The notification says it's my app.

Comment: @Jackey I updated my question with some code. I hope that's what you meant. I didn't include the api calls, though.

Comment: Is your StoreService a singleton? How are you managing it's resources? I'm asking since it appears like you're using the StoreService to do a lot of tasks and it's easy for these type of Singletons to hold onto too much resources. If I'm not reading your code wrong, are you storing your adapters inside a singleton? I'm talking about OfferAdapter inside OfferService and StoreAdapter inside StoreService. That's a serious issue, since Adapters are normally attached to Views and if you store them in Singletons, it's easy to get memory leaks.

Comment: Additionally, a lot of the code you're running on the UI Thread actually shouldn't be run on the UI thread. It's a bit concerning that it takes around 4 seconds for everything to load.

Comment: @Jackey Yes, we use Singleton and you saw the rest correctly, too. It's an issue I'm currently working on as well, but I didn't think that would have such an impact on the battery.